# Plot a piecewise-defined function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot the following function:

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda(\delta\tau) &\equiv\ \chi(\delta\tau, 0)
= \frac{1}{T_i} \int_0^{T_i} a(t_0+t')a(t_0+t'+\delta\tau) dt' \\
&= \begin{cases}
   1 - \frac{\left|\delta\tau\right|}{\tau_c}, &\left|\delta\tau\right| \le \tau_c(1+\frac{\tau_c}{T_i}) \\
   -\frac{\tau_c}{T_i}, &\left|\delta\tau\right| \gt \tau_c(1+\frac{\tau_c}{T_i}) \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
which represents a simple triangular shape. 
There is a conditional statement. My implementation uses a `for` loop as follows:

```
def waf_delay(delay_increment):
    for d in delay_increment:
        if np.abs(d) <= delay_chip*(1+delay_chip/integration_time):
            yield 1 - np.abs(d)/delay_chip
        else:
            yield -delay_chip/integration_time;

integration_time = 1e-3 # seconds
delay_chip =  1/1.023e6 # seconds

x=np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1) 
y=list(waf_delay(x))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Is there a more correct way to transform an array based on a condition rather than just looping through it? Instead of having something like this:

> ```
> def f(x_array):
>     for x in x_array:
>         if np.abs(x) <= 3:
>             yield 1 - x/3
>         else:
>             yield 0
>
> x=np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1) 
> y=list(f(x))
> plt.plot(x, y)
> plt.show()
> ```

I would like to write something like this:

> ```
> def f(x):
>         if np.abs(x) <= 3:
>             yield 1 - x/3
>         else:
>             yield 0
>
>
> x=np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1) 
> plt.plot(x, f(x))
> plt.show()
> ```

that could take an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem. The first one is [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which can take two arrays and it will choose from one wherever a condition is true and from the other wherever it is false. This only works if your piecewise function has only two possible states (as is the case here):

```
def waf_delay(delays):
    return np.where(np.abs(delays) <= delay_chip*(1+delay_chip/integration_time),
                    1 - np.abs(delays)/delay_chip,
                    -delay_chip/integration_time)
```

Another more general possibility is to use [`numpy.piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html), but that is probably overkill here:

```
def f1(x):
    return 1 - np.abs(x)/delay_chip

def f2(x):
    return -delay_chip/integration_time

cut_off = delay_chip*(1+delay_chip/integration_time)
y = np.piecewise(x, [np.abs(x) <= cut_off, np.abs(x) > cut_off], [f1, f2])
```

Note that in both cases no `for d in delays` is needed, because all functions used are vecotorized (the basic arithmetic operations for `numpy` arrays are and so is `numpy.abs`).

Comment: Very clean. This is exactly what I was expecting to be possible to do but I wasn't sure how. Do you have any recommendation on where to learn this algorithms?

Comment: @WooWapDaBug Looking at SO questions/answers about numpy and reading the documentation helped me to learn a lot about neat tricks. Also having to use it somewhere obviously helps, but I don't know of any tutorial that gets into the advanced stuff in a good way...

Comment: Graipher Very true. I try my best to learn and to contribute from SO. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. It is very valuable